# Is the DOC version of PTEX available anywhere?

Tags: tex-history, knuth, literate-programming

At the beginning of TeX: The Program we find that

> Preliminary plans to convert the SAIL code into a form
>   somewhat like the present "web" were developed by Luis Trabb-Pardo and
>   the author at the beginning of 1979, and a complete implementation was
>   created by Ignacio A. Zabala in 1979 and 1980.

In the very first issue of TUGboat there is an article by Trabb-Pardo and Zabala called ["The status of the Pascal implementation of TeX"](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb01-1/tb01zabala.pdf), which mentions the "extensively documented listings of `TEX`, `TEXPRE` and `SYSDEP`" (which were the three modules that comprised TeX at the time). Knuth's original paper on Literate Programming cites this article while talking about `WEB`'s predecessor `DOC` and mentions that "Ignacio Zabala Salelles
gave a `DOC` a thorough test when he prepared a full implementation
of TeX in PASCAL". Therefore we know that this Pascal version of TeX ("`PTEX`") was written using `DOC`.

The TUGboat article implies that `PTEX`'s files can be found on the SAIL computer at `[TEX,IAZ]`. The SAILDART archive has this password-protected. After a stupid amount of digging I managed to find the documented listing of the `SYSDEP` module mentioned above! It's not in the `DOC` format, but instead the "woven" (though this was of course pre-`WEAVE`) TeX form: [SYSDEP.TEX[TEX,ALS]](https://saildart.org/SYSDEP.TEX[TEX,ALS]). There's also what appears to be the main Pascal source of `PTEX` [here](https://saildart.org/TEX.PAS[TEX,ALS]1). I honestly don't know whether this is a pretty-printed version of the code produced by the `DOC` equivalent of `TANGLE` (I know that `DOC` didn't have the module number comments, so their absence makes sense) or if it's how it was distributed, but either way the `DOC` version is just out of reach.

I suppose that Mr. Zabala could be contacted, but before resorting to that, does anyone know where a copy of `PTEX` in its `DOC` form could be located?

Comment: Great find! The "DOC equivalent of TANGLE" was called "UNDOC" (mentioned e.g. [here (p. 361)](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb17-4/tb53knuc.pdf#page=8)). But that's no help. Also, like the TEX.PAS mentioned, there's also [TEXPRE.PAS](https://saildart.org/TEXPRE.PAS[TEX,ALS]) and [SYSDEP.PAS](https://saildart.org/SYSDEP.PAS[TEX,ALS]), which are together the UNDOC-generated sources for PTEX I guess. Also, another alternative to contacting Dr. Zabala may be to contact BGB of Saildart about making the `[TEX,IAZ]` area or specific files public, given their historical interest and references from outside.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR The UNDOC output procedure seems to be identical to TANGLE's, so these Pascal files must have been pretty-printed somehow---if they were in fact generated by UNDOC. Also, the acknowledgement comments at the beginning of the source files were placed manually, because UNDOC didn't have `@{` or `@=`. And that is a good suggestion; I might try it. PTEX would be fascinating to read, and with modifications, we might even be able to get WEAVE to format it.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR On second thought... the article doesn't say that `[TEX,IAZ]` is the actual location from where the sources can be obtained; it says only that the text of the report itself and a mailing list archive (which would be interesting to see, of course!) are accessible. The actual code, it says, is found at "the directory `(TEX.PASCAL)%SCORE`, accessible via the ARPANET". I would imagine that the sources are in `[TEX,IAZ]`, but whether or not the versions there were intended for the public is another story. So I hesitate to ask BGB.